# How to iterate through values in a dictionary

Tags: python

```
def countries(countries_dict):
    result = " "
    # Complete the for loop to iterate through the key and value items 
    # in the dictionary.

    for keys in countries_dict.values():
            for i in range(1,4):
                result += str(keys)
                return result

print(countries({"Africa": ["Kenya", "Egypt", "Nigeria"], "Asia":["China", "India", "Thailand"], "South America": ["Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Brazil"]}))

# Should print:
# ['Kenya', 'Egypt', 'Nigeria']
# ['China', 'India', 'Thailand']
# ['Ecuador', 'Bolivia', 'Brazil']
```

This is the code. I know my mistake is somewhere in the iteration but have no idea how to fix it

I thought adding another `for i in range()` and making iterate 4 times would print the appropriate result but it didn't. I'm only getting the values from Africa and no other ones.

Comment: `return` makes the function exit immediately, so the for loop only runs once...

Comment: @JohnGordon I switched it out with print and made appropriate changes, it's giving me a "None" which I need to use return to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you return a value during the first loop iteration, which exits the whole function. Instead, you want to accumulate the strings of the values in `result`, then call `return result` at the end of the function (outside of the loop).

You can also simplify your code a bit. Like this:

```
def countries(countries_dict):
    result = ""
    for lst in countries_dict.values():
        result += str(lst) + '\n'
    return result[:-1]


print(countries({"Africa": ["Kenya", "Egypt", "Nigeria"],
                 "Asia":["China", "India", "Thailand"],
                 "South America": ["Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Brazil"]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def countries(countries_dict):
    result = ""
    # Complete the for loop to iterate through the key and value items 
    # in the dictionary.
    for key in countries_dict.values():
        # Use a string method to format the required string.
        result += str(key) + "\n"
    return result

print(countries({"Africa": ["Kenya", "Egypt", "Nigeria"], "Asia":["China", "India", "Thailand"], "South America": ["Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Brazil"]}))
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest iterative code basically takes two lines, and does not make a function call:

```
for x in {"Africa": ["Kenya", "Egypt", "Nigeria"], 
             "Asia":["China", "India", "Thailand"], 
             "South America": ["Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Brazil"]}.values():
    print(x)
```

Note the 'values()' method call.

If you prefer to use a function call, then the following code will achieve the same result:

```
# define the function (printing happens in here)
def countries(countries_view):
        for x in countries_view:
            print(x)

# call the function, no printing at this level, printing is done in the function
countries({"Africa": ["Kenya", "Egypt", "Nigeria"], 
             "Asia":["China", "India", "Thailand"], 
             "South America": ["Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Brazil"]}.values())
```

Note that it is NOT 'print(countries...)' but just 'countries()'.